# ¿Por qué hay una diferencia en la respuesta dependiendo de los formatos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Estoy intentando acceder a [una API que me envía información sobre libros](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.show_by_isbn). Me gustaría particularmente obtener los "Shelves" (estantes). Cuando accedo a ellos a través de [la url](https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/0380795272?key=pU8aWDMPyBMZ45ObUtZyg) no tengo ningún problema.

```
<GoodreadsResponse>
...
<authors>
<author>
<id>18</id>
<name>Gary Paulsen</name>
<role/>
<image_url nophoto="false">
<![CDATA[
https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1309159225p5/18.jpg
]]>
</image_url>
<small_image_url nophoto="false">
<![CDATA[
https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1309159225p2/18.jpg
]]>
</small_image_url>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/18.Gary_Paulsen
]]>
</link>
<average_rating>3.77</average_rating>
<ratings_count>427417</ratings_count>
<text_reviews_count>30355</text_reviews_count>
</author>
</authors>
<reviews_widget>
<![CDATA[
<style> #goodreads-widget { font-family: georgia, serif; padding: 18px 0; width:565px; } #goodreads-widget h1 { font-weight:normal; font-size: 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB596; margin-bottom: 0; } #goodreads-widget a { text-decoration: none; color:#660; } iframe{ background-color: #fff; } #goodreads-widget a:hover { text-decoration: underline; } #goodreads-widget a:active { color:#660; } #gr_footer { width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #BBB596; text-align: right; } #goodreads-widget .gr_branding{ color: #382110; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; } </style> <div id="goodreads-widget"> <div id="gr_header"><h1><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50.Hatchet">Hatchet Reviews</a></h1></div> <iframe id="the_iframe" src="https://www.goodreads.com/api/reviews_widget_iframe?did=DEVELOPER_ID&amp;format=html&amp;isbn=0689840926&amp;links=660&amp;min_rating=&amp;review_back=fff&amp;stars=000&amp;text=000" width="565" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe> <div id="gr_footer"> <a class="gr_branding" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50.Hatchet?utm_medium=api&amp;utm_source=reviews_widget">Reviews from Goodreads.com</a> </div> </div>
]]>
</reviews_widget>
<popular_shelves>
<shelf name="to-read" count="42731"/>
<shelf name="currently-reading" count="4063"/>
<shelf name="young-adult" count="2452"/>
<shelf name="fiction" count="1960"/>
<shelf name="adventure" count="1052"/>
<shelf name="favorites" count="1027"/>
<shelf name="classics" count="909"/>
<shelf name="ya" count="832"/>
```

Pero cuando intento acceder a él por código (`goodreads.py`), solo obtengo una parte de la respuesta que recibí a través de la URL.

Aquí esta el código de `goodreads.py`:

```
#get every books from the csv file

# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data = pd.read_csv("books.csv", nrows=10)
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
print(data.head())

for i,row in data.iterrows():
    res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn", params={"id": data['isbn'][i], "user_id": 49393496, "format":"json"})
    parsed = json.loads(res.text)
    print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))

print(data.head())
```

Y aquí esta la respuesta del terminal:

```
(col_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\collective_intelligence>python goodreads.py
         isbn                  title            author  year
0  0380795272  Krondor: The Betrayal  Raymond E. Feist  1998
1  1416949658     The Dark Is Rising      Susan Cooper  1973
2  1857231082     The Black Unicorn       Terry Brooks  1987
3  0553803700               I, Robot      Isaac Asimov  1950
4  080213825X           Four Blondes  Candace Bushnell  2000
{'reviews_widget': '<style>\n  #goodreads-widget {\n    font-family: georgia, serif;\n    padding: 18px 0;\n    width:565px;\n  }\n  #goodreads-widget h1 {\n    font-weight:normal;\n    font-size: 16px;\n    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB596;\n    margin-bottom: 0;\n  }\n  #goodreads-widget a {\n    text-decoration: none;\n    color:#660;\n  }\n  iframe{\n    background-color: #fff;\n  }\n  #goodreads-widget a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }\n  #goodreads-widget a:active {\n    color:#660;\n  }\n  #gr_footer {\n    width: 100%;\n    border-top: 1px solid #BBB596;\n    text-align: right;\n  }\n  #goodreads-widget .gr_branding{\n    color: #382110;\n    font-size: 11px;\n    text-decoration: none;\n    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n</style>\n<div id="goodreads-widget">\n  <div id="gr_header"><h1><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92918.Krondor">Krondor Reviews</a></h1></div>\n  <iframe id="the_iframe" src="https://www.goodreads.com/api/reviews_widget_iframe?did=DEVELOPER_ID&amp;format=html&amp;isbn=0380795272&amp;links=660&amp;review_back=fff&amp;stars=000&amp;text=000" width="565" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>\n  <div id="gr_footer">\n    <a class="gr_branding" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92918.Krondor?utm_medium=api&amp;utm_source=reviews_widget">Reviews from Goodreads.com</a>\n  </div>\n</div>\n'}
```

Solo obtengo `reviews_widget`.

¿Por qué hay una diferencia en la respuesta dependiendo de los formatos?

¿Cómo obtener todos los resultados de la solicitud y especialmente los estantes?

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que el contenido ofrecido depende totalmente de la implementación del proveeedor de la API. Ten en cuenta que el recurso que accedes es principalmente para *reviews*. Por otro lado, cuando se consultan los *reviews* por ID, nota lo que menciona la documentación (https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.show)

> Get the reviews for a book given a Goodreads book id:
>
> [...]
>
> **XML responses also include shelves** and book meta-data (title, author, et cetera). [...]
>
> **If you need book meta-data beyond what our API provides, consider signing up for an Amazon developer key.**